# md-autocomplete with multiselect check box and two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material, multi-select

I'm trying to implement autocomplete dropdown with multiselect option check box,
so when user search a text it should display the items with check box options. And the user can select multiple items on that.

Once the user select the items, it should display the list of selected items below the dropdown with delete options.

The selected items are stored in an object array.

I did this with the below combination,

```
<md-autocomplete class="md-primary" md-no-cache="true"
                                 md-selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
                                 md-search-text="vm.searchText"
                                 md-items="item in vm.find(vm.searchText)"
                                 md-item-text="item.Name"
                                 md-min-length="3"
                                 placeholder="Type here to search...">
                    <md-item-template>
                        <md-checkbox ng-click="vm.ItemSelected(item, $event)" stop-event></md-checkbox>
                        <div>
                            <span class="item-title">
                                <span md-highlight-text="vm.searchText">{{item.Name}}</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </md-item-template>
                    <md-not-found>
                        No items were found.
                    </md-not-found>
                </md-autocomplete>
```

Using directive "stop-event" with event.stopPropagation() to prevent dropdown from collapsing after click.

But what the issue is, i can't bind the search result items with the already selected items.

There is no option to mark as checked from the search list if the item is already selected.

I've searched for the fixes, all were said to use the md-chips, but i want to do it with the md-autocomplete.

Can someone help me on this?